# React router dynamic url no redirecting me to the desired page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I want to access component according to the id of the product.
Here is my Code.

**List.jsx**

```
import { Switch, Route, Redirect, withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import CategoryList from "./CategoryList.jsx";
import ProductList from "./ProductList.jsx";

import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const CategoryWithId = ({ match }) => {
  console.log("Category", match.params.listId);

  <ProductList listId={match.params.listId}></ProductList>;
};

function List() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState([]);

  const getList = () => {
    axios.get("https://api.growcify.com/dev/category/list").then((res) => {
      console.log(res.data);
      setState(res.data);
    });
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    getList();
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={() => <CategoryList state={state} />} />
        <Route path="/product/:listId" component={CategoryWithId} />
        <Redirect to="/" />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}

export default withRouter(List);
```

**CategoryList.jsx**

```
import React from "react";

import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { Typography } from "@material-ui/core";


const ShowCategory = (props) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const { list } = props;
  return (
    <Link to={`/product/${list._id}`}>
      <Paper className={classes.paper} key={list._id}>
        <p style={{ position: "relative", top: "40%" }}>{list.name}</p>
      </Paper>
    </Link>
  );
};

function CategoryList(props) {
  const { state } = props;
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <>
      <div className={classes.header}>
        <Typography variant="h3" style={{ padding: "10px" }}>
          List of Categories
        </Typography>
      </div>
      <div className={classes.container}>
        <Grid container className={classes.root} spacing={2}>
          <Grid item xs={12}>
            <Grid container spacing={2}>
              {state.map((list, index) => (
                <ShowCategory list={list}></ShowCategory>
              ))}
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default CategoryList;
```

I want that on clicking on Particular category, i should be redirect to /produce/listId.

In the url section, I can see the url with listId but I'm not getting redirected to the desired page related to that url.

[image]

Comment: Provide `exact` on both routes, or at least in the first one. `<Route exact `. Did you use `BrowserRouter` or `Router` anywhere?

Comment: Does reload after the link update render the product?

Comment: Can you add from which component you're rendering CategoryWithId and how you're wrapping the component with <BrowserRouter />?

Comment: Yeah,Thank You! Providing exact to the Router worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use exact keyword!

```
<Route exact path="/" component={() => <CategoryList state={state} />} />
```